# What is the solution of the equation $\sin x \cos x -\sin^2 x =\frac14(\sqrt{6}-2)$?

Tags: calculus, geometry, trigonometry

Frankly this question puzzled me too:
How to solve the following equation :

$$\sin x \cos x -\sin^2 x =\frac{\sqrt{6}-2}{4}$$

I tried so much to no avail.
I have reached this formula, but I did not know the solution

$$2\sin x+\cos x=\frac12 \sqrt{6}$$

Can you help me?

Comment: You cannot present your problem this way. First, see how to use MathJAx. Without appropriate presentation, you are not going to receive any answers.

Comment: It is hardly intelligible, what you've tried!

Comment: @Shaun No offence, but you should at least have rotated the image!

Comment: I can't do that on my phone, @NashJ.

Comment: @Shaun I agree!

Comment: @anas, See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2594442/find-the-range-of-fx-11-cos2x3-sin2x6-sin-x-cos-x5/2594459#2594459

Comment: This is very hard to read. Can you format with mathjax please?

Answer (score 1):

$$\sin(x)\cos(x) - \sin^2(x) = C$$

Where $C$ is your right hand side constant for simplicity.

Use trigonometric identities to rewrite it as

$$\frac{1}{2}\sin(2x) - \frac{1 - \cos(2x)}{2} = C$$

$$\sin(2x) + \cos(2x) = 2C + 1$$

Call $x = z/2$

$$\sin(z) + \cos(z) = 2C + 1$$

Square both

$$1 + 2\sin(z)\cos(z) = (2C +1)^2$$

$$\sin(2z) = (2C +1)^2 - 1$$

From here you can continue by yourself!

Comment: Thanks for helping you ,I do not know what I am doing now to find z $$\sin(2z) = \frac{3-2\sqrt{6}}{4}$$  .Please help me and sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: The problem is that I only know the solution to the usual angles

Comment: Have you studied the inverse trigonometric functions?

Comment: No, we did not study it . I am studying now in the first baccalaureate

Comment: Avoid squaring which immediately introduces extraneous root(s)

Comment: @labbhattacharjee TRUE!

Answer (score 1):

You need the duplication formulæ to solve:
\begin{align}
&\sin x\cos x - \sin^2x=\frac12\sin 2x-\frac{1-\cos 2x}2=\frac14(\sqrt 6-2)\\
\iff & \sin 2x+\cos 2x=\frac{\sqrt 6}2.
\end{align}

Now $\;\sin 2x+\cos 2x=\sqrt 2\biggl(\dfrac{\sqrt 2}2\sin 2x+\dfrac{\sqrt 2}2\cos 2x\biggr)=\sqrt 2\sin\Bigl(2x+\dfrac\pi 4\Bigr)$, so the equation is equivalent to
$$\sin\Bigl(2x+\dfrac\pi 4\Bigr)=\frac{\sqrt 3}2=\sin\frac\pi 3.$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I have not noticed him before.